# Proving that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)(n+1)!} < \frac e2 - \frac 76$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to prove the the inequality below.

$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)(n+1)!} < \frac e2 - \frac 76$

But I did not understand the first steps of the solution,

$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)(n+1)!} = \frac 1{3!} + \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)(n+1)!} < \frac 1{3!} + \frac 12 \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$

How do we get $\frac 12 \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at it term-by-term:
\begin{align*}
\frac1{(3-1)(3+1)!}&=\frac12\frac1{(3+1)!}\\
\frac1{(4-1)(4+1)!}&<\frac12\frac1{(4+1)!}\\
\frac1{(5-1)(5+1)!}&<\frac12\frac1{(5+1)!}\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

For $n = 3$ we have $n-1 =2$ and for $n \ge 4$ we have $n-1 >2.$ Hence  $\frac{1}{n-1}< \frac{1}{2}$ for $n \ge 4.$